# Aligning divs using the baselines of child divs in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can align two `div`'s by simply setting their `display` to `inline-block` and using same `line-height`s like shown in the below:

[image: single divs]

However, what I want is that aligning two nested divs according to the baseline of the inner divs like this:

[image: nested divs]

I can achieve this also using jquery by taking the longest heading's height and set all the headings' height to this value.

```
var fitSizes = function () {
    var h = 0;
    $('h1').each( function(){
        if(h < $(this).outerHeight()) h = $(this).outerHeight();
        // select biggest height
    });
    $('h1').each( function(){
        $(this).outerHeight(h);
        // set all h1 heights to the biggest height
    });
};

fitSizes();
```

But for some reasons I don't want to use `js` or `jquery`. Is there any "`CSS` only" way to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Any solution I can think of here seems hacky, as are usually problems of this nature. There is ALWAYS a scenario where they will break. A programmatic approach, however bloated and ugly, will definitely give you exactly what you want.

I'm going to make an assumption that both the header and the content are of varying lengths and there may be more than just 2 on page either on a single line or multiple.

**TOP DOWN APPROACH // fixed header height**

There's no reason why your approach above won't work for a nested div. I would wrap the h1 if you're applying styles to it though. Setting a line-height on a h1 if it breaks across lines will cause each line in the multiline to have that line height. Wrap the header in a div and give that a static height, that way if the  has styles such as a background won't be affected by the "margin".

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        height: 2.5rem;
        line-height: 2.5rem;
        text-align: bottom;
        // flex approach works too
    }
    h1 {
        line-height: 1rem;
    }
</style>
...
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>lorem ipsum....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**"BOTTOM UP" APPROACH // fixed content**

This would work better if the "anchor" for these components is the bottom of the page. If your content varies in length you could fix the height of the container and content.

```
<style>
    .container {
        text-align: bottom;
    }
    h1 {
        line-height: 1rem;
    }
    .content {
        height: 15rem;
        overflow: elipsis;
    }
</style>
...
<div class="container">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <p>lorem ipsum....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's just so much to think about that's unclear. How can you help knowing you're giving the best answer you can without knowing these things... It gives me anxiety, haha. Flexbox solves the question in the simplest of scenarios, but when is a scenario ever "simple"?

Comment: If I gave static heights to my headers, I should set it manually for any possible screen sizes which is not possible. I think when we talk about dynamic contents, there is no way other than the javascript :) Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), you could set make the outer div's siblings by making a container around them and do something like this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

If this does not fulfill your needs you could also try and see if `align-items: baseline;` fixes it. Just have a look at flexbox.

Comment: Thank you for your attention but I have two different divs and the alignment baseline I want is inside of this divs. As I know, the flexbox align its childs according to their own baselines, not the headings inside of that childs. This is not what I want. Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mctEf1oQLrnB7M5F4XGB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

What You are looking for using flexbox.

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  
  height: 300px;

  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  /* position at bottom of container */
  margin-top: auto;
  /* spread inside container */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* align items in row and center it verticaly */
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  
  margin: auto 5px 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  /* spread inside container */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* align items in column, and position content at the bottom */ 
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.row {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
      <span class="row">row one</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <span class="row">row one</span>
      <span class="row">row two</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is something up and coming that would be really useful to use.  It's only growing in popularity.

This can answer many different problems.  Such as your justification issue.
Here's a simple fiddle with little code that shows the answer to your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/hkLk53c6/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    Item
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    Item
    <br>
    Item
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    Item
    <br>
    Item
    <br>
    Item
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #333; 
 }

.flex-item {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #120321;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Here's a link to Chris Coyier's explanation about Flexbox Properties:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I've personally found it very useful in learning more about flexbox.

You can styled based off of the baseline, you can reverse elements, justify them to be the same height both vertically and horizontally.  Etc.  It's very exciting because now we can get past some hacky fixes. (Like using JS which trust me, you're not the only one to do so far!)

Comment: Flexbox is good for many problems, but this is not what I am looking for and the fiddle you referenced is not solving my problem. Thank you for your answer but I think there is no css solution to solve exactly my problem.

Comment: Actually, you're right.  I think I misunderstood the question until looking at it again.  You're actually talking about matching the baseline of the headers in seperate elements. 
I was looking at it as one element that was changing.  My apologies.  If I find a solution, i'll be sure to edit my post.